# SATA electrostatic discharge in laptop

Tags: hard-drive

I have been so foolish to accidentally touch my HDD while my laptop was running. I was listening for some weird sound and therefore needed to open it up while it was turned on, but touched the hard drive and suddenly the laptop turned off, BIOS was shown and "no media" message appeared. Of course I know what happened, but I don't really mind that, because I use the M2 SSD and not the Hdd in the laptop, which is why I wonder why I got the "no media" message, as the Hdd was empty.
I reinstalled windows on the SSD. Everything is working fine, no high temperatures,  nothing weird. 
The only wrong thing now is that the laptop cannot detect any HDD in the SATA slot anymore. I haven't tried the HDD on another laptop to check if it's dead, but I can confirm the SATA cable in the laptop cannot read any HDD anymore. 
My question is, as I don't care about the HDD, will other components be dead on the motherboard now? How can I know? Is there some protection so the other parts of the motherboard doesn't die? If I change the SATA cable, would it perhaps work again?

Comment: Sounds like you should come back when you know if the HDD is functional or not.

Comment: I don't really care about the HDD, I only care about the laptop itself.

Comment: It sounds like a case where the HDD is simply not functional.  Why don't you try a different cable and verify if the HDD is dead?

Comment: if you know for sure cable is not working then maybe hard disk is OK, if this is the case then its very possible that no other components got fried, since nothing goes after the HD itself, its like the endline. if SDD and OS in general is working fine, then you can be 99% sure nothing else got fried.

Comment: Are you saying that you tried a different, known-working, HDD and that didn't work? If so, the only options are that the HDD is not getting power, the SATA connector is faulty, the SATA cable is faulty, or the SATA port is faulty.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify myself.  I just want to know if ESD damage on my HDD can destroy other motherboard components

Comment: I have tried another working hdd that didn't work on the laptop too

Comment: If the motherboard appears to be in a working condition then it's unlikely you caused any additional ESD damage other then to your HDD.  However, there is no way for us to know for sure, it either is functional or it isn't.

Comment: Every input/output first element is any kind of transistor. The layers can burn through on ESD. Within a well-engineered IC, this is the only thing what can be burn, but this is enough for the port become unavailable. Meaning IO pin become shorted to ground or IO high voltage. This not kill the connected hardware (the HDD). So you have small chance to any other die, particuralry mSata and SATA controlled by same chip. Also manufacturers use to add "sata re-drivers", which add extra protection for the main components.

Comment: Previous comment can apply on sata drive too, so damaged SATA drive cannot kill a motherboard, malfunctional sata port cannot kill a sata drive.

Comment: So it's not possible that esd damage destroyed a few other components but the motherboard would still be working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to know if ESD damage on my HDD can destroy other motherboard components

It is possible, but not very likely.

Random every day acts like walking on carpet or wearing ESD-prone clothing can charge you with a few thousand volts. The laptop (whether grounded or not connected to anything) will be at a different potential.

Therefore, when you touch a conductive part of the laptop, there will be an electrostatic discharge as your body and the laptop's potentials equalize.

These discharges are enough to fry pretty much any electronic chip, but only if the current caused by the discharge flows through a sensitive part.

This is why all the IO on your laptop includes ESD protection (like USB ports, etc). Next time if you want to do it safely, plug a USB cable in one of the ports, and hold the cable at the other end by the connector shield. The discharge current will flow in the shields and ground, without damaging anything.

If you touched the ground, or the shield, or the metallic part of the HDD, then it should be OK.

However, if the ESD occured between your finger and a chip on the HDD PCB, then obviously the manufacturer would not have included ESD protection at this particular place, since it is not supposed to be exposed to ESD. Chips on a board are usually a lot more ESD-resistant than when unsoldered, because the current has a lot more paths to flow into ground without destroying anything on the way. But if you're unlucky, and you zap the board with a nasty discharge, then yes, you can zap one of the chips, and it can propagate along the traces and zap anything on the way like the SATA chip on the mobo.

That would be rather bad luck, but it is possible.

The fact it made the PC crash is a hint that you hit a sensitive spot.

Testing with a known good HDD will reveal if the mobo has taken damage or not. Also the zapped HDD itself may still work if you try it in another PC.

If the mobo has taken damage, most likely it will be inside the chip at the other end of the SATA lines. The only other pins on the SATA connector are ground and power, and power isn't ESD-sensitive due to the amount of decoupling capacitors present, which will short the discharge to ground.

Comment: Very good answer. I did not touch the board itself, I touched the metallic part of the harddisk (the hdd was still screwed, so it was the upper part), it actually did not make the PC crash, it just seemed to make the bios think no hdd or ssd was inserted, but I am using the esd now and it's completely fine.

Comment: When you say chip what do you mean exactly? I have tested other working hdd in my laptop, and they don't work in my laptop, so I know something Is wrong with the sata cable, or the sata port maybe.

Comment: Chip = any integrated circuit. If you touched the metal part, and it did some damage, you were really unlucky. Did you feel your finger get zapped? Did you touch any metal part of the laptop to discharge your static before touching the HDD?

Comment: I discharged myself yes, I did not feel anything.

Comment: An ESD you don't feel can still fry electronics, but if you touched the laptop ground a few seconds before, when did you build up the charge? It's really really weird.

Comment: I dont Know Much about electronics sorry, but the laptop fans has stops working, the sound stopped working too. I called Lenovo and it will be sent for repair tomorrow.

Comment: @peufeu - You cannot see a static build up.  So asking "how did you build up the charge" cannot be answered.  There is a reason you should ground yourself properly to earth ground, not hold a USB cable, the USB method won't actually ground you.

Comment: I was wondering if he was wearing wool, stuff like that. I agree with your comment, actually I have the ESD mat and wrist strap etc, but without proper equipment, staying in contact with the computer's ground is still better than nothing...